# Which factors determine which pole is going to be N and S in the broken pieces of the magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

Let's suppose that there is a magnet with a north and south pole and we break this magnet randomly. Which factors determine which pole is going to be N and S in the broken pieces of the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

The part which contains the old north pole will have to get a new south pole, and vice versa, like this picture:

[image]

If the old north pole piece gets another new north pole, you end up with a [magnetic monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole); those haven't been experimentally observed yet. Due to the [divergenceless property of magnetic fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108224), we don't observe these monopoles, though they have been hypothesized to be exist at sufficiently high energies.